# Select records that fail casting varchar column to bigint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

is there an easy way to get all records where casting a varchar column to an bigint would fail? This causes a conversion error:

```
SELECT CAST(IMEI AS BIGINT)FROM RMA
```

Use this sql as example:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RMA') is not null
    DROP TABLE #RMA

CREATE TABLE #RMA
( 
    IMEI VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO  #RMA(IMEI)VALUES('352382021485772')
INSERT INTO  #RMA(IMEI)VALUES('352022033456409')
INSERT INTO  #RMA(IMEI)VALUES('BN332VWY653577440220')

SELECT * FROM  #RMA
SELECT CAST(IMEI AS BIGINT)FROM #RMA

DROP TABLE #RMA
```

So, in this example i need only the record with IMEI='BN332VWY653577440220'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the T-SQL `ISNUMERIC` function:

```
SELECT IMEI 
FROM  #RMA
WHERE ISNUMERIC(IMEI) = 0   -- not numeric
```

See the [MSDN SQL Server Books Online docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) for it.

Comment: Oh, i forgot that function. Thanks

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: you can always rely on Stackoverflow as your "extended memory" ;-)